# How to render Dynamic paint?

Tags: dynamic-paint

I have a Dynamic paint scene that looks cool in view port but when i render the animation nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: I am sure _something_ is happening. Is this something that just happens in this particular project? Have you ever managed to render out an animation successfully?

Comment: ...2.79.1 sounds like an unreleased/custom version, have you tried with an official/stable one?

Comment: Yes i was renedering with 2.79.1 version that was the problem.